# Joomla Navigation Question

Tags: joomla, navigation

I'm brand new to Joomla but after browsing around a demo site and doing some reading I think it may be the solution I'm looking for. I just have one question regarding navigation.

The site I'm building will need a fairly complex navigation system. The organization I work for offers many programs open to their clients. Each program is represented by its own set of pages on the website. This set of pages is comprised of: "Info", "Dates", "Pricing", "Contacts", etc. Totaling about 5 pages for each program.

To navigate between these pages, we'd like to have a horizontal navigation that is standard between all program pages. This nav bar will link between pages that are in a given program set but won't link to others. Is there a way to accomplish this in Joomla without having to manually create links on each page for all 70 programs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

joomla supports navigation with the help of menus. There are components and modules written to support menus. like com_menu and mod_menu. The table which contains menu structure is jos_menus. To see and create menu structure you can login to admin section and click on menu and create menus.If you need more info let me know.

Comment: Sounds good! I did a little research and it looks like I should be able to set the programs as categories and find a module to automatically create a menu based on the content in those categories.

Comment: If you are creating Site Navigation you should try to use Menus rather than categories. Categories solve different purpose (tagging) in joomla. And at a point when you will need sub navigation. You will be stuck with categories.